# How to set x frame option in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

As I found it can be easily set in Apache server:
x-frame-options=allow in httpd-conf file

but how about tomcat? I am working with a version 7.0.57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat only support a config from 7.0.63 above version.

Answer (score 9):

In Tomcat you need to use filters for that:

First, implement your own `Filter`. Something like this:

```
public class XFrameHeaderFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException {
        ((HttpServletResponse) resp).setHeader("x-frame-options", "allow");
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Second, make this filter a part of your web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>x-frame-header</filter-name>
  <filter-class>XFrameHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>x-frame-header</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Don't forget `chain.doFilter(req, resp) ;` at the end of `#doFilter()`

Comment: Oh, sure! Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

after tomcat 7.0.63

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

For filter-mapping part I have added.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: you have added filter mapping for request dispatcher also. why?

Comment: org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter is this class inbuilt in java or tomcat or need to import ?